# Date always get different getTime()

Tags: java, date

I'm wondering why I always get a difference between this date in milliseconds.

Any idea ?

Here is the output :

```
date = 1572794103293 ms 
date2 = 1572794103341 ms  
date3 = 1572794103341 ms  
date4 = 1572794103341 ms
```

and here is the code :

```
Date date = createDate();
Date date2 = createDate();
Date date3 = createDate();
Date date4 = createDate();
System.out.println(date.getTime());
System.out.println(date2.getTime());
System.out.println(date3.getTime());
System.out.println(date4.getTime());

private static Date createDate() {
      Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        c.set(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 03, 16, 15, 03);
        return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Because you don't set the milliseconds with `set` so each `GregorianCalendar` will use it's own. `set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)`.

Comment: Oh, I thought the question was why there is a difference between `date` and the rest, but none between `date2`, `date3` and `date4`.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Yes i'd like an answer to that to.

Comment: There is no difference because the call was to quick probably. It doesn't take much time to create an instance.

Comment: @AxelH Yes, but it's reproducibly quicker on any consecutive call after the first. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of [`Calendar.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), it is said :

> Sets the values for the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. Previous values of other fields are retained. If this is not desired, call [clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29) first.

The reason is that not all fields are set with this method, in you case, you don't have `MILLISECOND` set. So it keep the value when the instance was created.

The call of [`Calendar.clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29) will

> Sets all the calendar field values and the time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch) of this Calendar undefined.

A quick example :

```
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    c.clear();
    c.set(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 03, 16, 15, 03);

    System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

> 1572794103000

Milliseconds being undefined will give 0

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments and AxelH's answer mentioning the fact that the milliseconds of a `Calendar` instance aren't changed by `Calendar.set`, there is still the curiosity that you get the same value for `date2`, `date3` and `date4`, but a different value for `date`.

This is because the very first time you call `createDate()` the JVM has to initialize the `Date` class, which happens after `Calendar c` was initialized.

Thus on the first call `c.getTime()` needs more time than on the consecutive calls, which you can see as the difference between the value of `date` and the other 3 instances.

If you add a call to `new Date()` before the first call to `createDate()`, the  difference between each value should be the same.

**Please note that this does not fix your issue**, it just hides it if your machine is fast enough. It's merely an explanation for the particular values you get.

Comment: That's not an important problem, those calls will never be done in sequence, it would be call in different time, different request, so the milliseconds values would be more "random".